# Configuring Google closure compiler for OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am following [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/closure.html) tutorial but I cannot run this command

```
./node_modules/openlayers/node_modules/.bin/closure-util
```

It says "no such file or directory" when I followed the folder structure indeed there was no such file

What am I doing wrong? is there change in structure? I am guessing this is old.

My node version is 7.6.0 and my npm version is 4.1.2 and I am trying to compile OpenLayers version ^4.0.1 as declared in package.json

Answer (score 1):

Found a way it looks like the directory structure was old the closure lib is
entirely separate its

```
./node_modules/closure-util/bin/closure-util.js
```

This worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 I guess the tutorial has to be updated.